# PostgreSQL sql standard

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know that PostgreSQL is the closest database to full SQL compliance. I am however wondering where postgres does not comply to the standard, and I am unable to find it in their documentation.

What features of SQL does PostgreSQL lack, and what features does it offer outside the SQL standard?

Comment: Each SQL statement documented has a section "Compatibility" which documents if and how the SQL statement complies or deviates from the standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is Appendix D of the PostgreSQL documentation on SQL standard conformance:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/features.html

Take a special look at D.2 for unsupported features.

Comment: I have also found another list at: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_vs_SQL_Standard